# QGIS - how to see the minimum and maximum elevations in contour layer

Tags: qgis, contour

I am using QGIS 2.12 on a Macbook Pro running OS X Yosemite 10.10.5.

I have a contour layer representing elevations. How can I find what the maximum and minimum elevation values in the layer?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a vector layer with the elevation as an attribute, you can open the attribute table and click on the column title of the elevation field. This will change the sorting from low to high and from high to low (or the other way around). You can also use the statist plugins to get statistics of that field.

Comment: Another method is to use _Vector > Analysis Tools > Basic Statistics_ on the `elevation` field to obtain maximum, minimum and other values.

Comment: @Techie_Gus -- It is strange, but although it is a shapefile (vector file), there is only 1 column in the attribute table. It is titled "ID" and has integers in sequence from 0 to 26381. So no elevation data are shown in the attribute table! Thank you for looking at this.

Comment: @Joseph -- It is strange, but this contour shapefile has no elevation field! I created it from a raster DEM, using Raster -> Analysis -> DEM (Terrain Models)... .

Comment: @Catlike - Do you mean you created the shapefile using Raster > Extraction > Contour from a DEM?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry -- you are correct. I did use Raster -> Extraction -> Contour from a DEM.

Comment: @Catlike remember to enable "Attribute name" in the dialog box, otherwise an elevation field is not created.